# Colocar iconos abajo de la pantalla dentro de Sidebar

Tags: html5, css3, bootstrap-4

He intentado sin éxito colocar iconos de redes sociales abajo de mi `sidebar`, este inconveniente es únicamente cuando mi `sidebar` se encuentra contraído pero cuando se expande puedo posicionar mis elementos donde deseo , sin problema alguno.

Mis iconos se encuentran dentro de un `ul` que a su vez está dentro de un `div` y este dentro de un elemento `aside`.

Cuando mi `sidebar` se expande soy capaz de agregarle una propiedad absoluta a mi `li` y posicionarle según su clase.

```
.facebookBOTTOM10 {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 10%;
}

.instagramBOTTOM5 {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 5%;
}

.twitterBOTTOM0 {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0%;
}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esto no sucede cuando se contrae porque la clase (`.left-side-menu-condensed`)que se encarga de contraer el `sidebar` y se aplica a mi elemento `<body>` de alguna forma me asigna una propiedad relativa a todos mis elementos, pensando en esto creí que especificando o que agregando un `!important` a mi `li` para posicionarlo de forma absoluta me resolveria. (*entiendo que `!important` no es la mejor solución, pero he intentado tambien usando un `id`, con el mismo resultado*)

Este es mi resultado:

```
.left-side-menu-condensed .page-wrapper .side-navbar .metismenu .facebookBOTTOM10 {
    position: absolute!important;
    bottom: 10%;
}

.left-side-menu-condensed .page-wrapper .side-navbar .metismenu .instagramBOTTOM5 {
    position: absolute!important;
    bottom: 5%;
}

.left-side-menu-condensed .page-wrapper .side-navbar .metismenu .twitterBOTTOM0 {
    position: absolute!important;
    bottom: 0%;
}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como última instancia he decidido agregar un atributo extra que es `top` para posicionar mi elemento en píxeles y funciona como deseo.

Este es mi resultado:

```
.left-side-menu-condensed .page-wrapper .side-navbar .metismenu .facebookBOTTOM10 {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0%;
    top: 850px;
}

.left-side-menu-condensed .page-wrapper .side-navbar .metismenu .instagramBOTTOM5 {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0%;
    top: 900px;
}

.left-side-menu-condensed .page-wrapper .side-navbar .metismenu .twitterBOTTOM0 {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0%;
    top: 950px;
}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**"El problema"** con esta solución es que debo estar aplicando `media-queries` para ir posicionando mis elementos desde de un `max-width:1680px` hasta un `min-width:1280px`, entonces me pregunto si alguien me puede ayudar a encontrar una forma de hacerlo de la misma manera que cuando mi `sidebar` está expandido.

Agradeceria cualquier comentario:

Código de ejemplo:

```
<aside class="side-navbar">
    <div class="scroll-content" id="metismenu">
        <div>
            <ul id="side-menu" class="metismenu list-unstyled">
                <li class="side-nav-title side-nav-item menu-title"></li>
                <li>
                    <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="side-nav-link" aria-expanded="false">
                        <i class="bx bx-home-circle"></i>
                        <span> Inicio </span>
                        <span class="menu-arrow"></span>
                    </a>
                    <ul aria-expanded="false" class="nav-second-level">

                        <li class="side-nav-item">
                            <a class="side-nav-link" href="us.php"> Nosotros </a>
                        </li>

                        <li class="side-nav-item">
                            <a class="side-nav-link" href="politicas_uso.php"> Pol&iacute;ticas de uso </a>
                        </li>

                    </ul>
                </li>

                <li class="side-nav-title side-nav-item menu-title">MEN&Uacute;</li>
                <li>
                    <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="side-nav-link" aria-expanded="false">
                        <i class="bx bxs-envelope"></i>
                        <span> Cont&aacute;ctenos</span>
                        <span class="menu-arrow"></span>
                    </a>
                    <ul aria-expanded="false" class="nav-second-level">
                        <li class="side-nav-item">
                            <a class="side-nav-link" href="atencion_cliente.php"> Atenci&oacute;n al cliente </a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="side-nav-item">
                            <a class="side-nav-link" href="javascript:void(0);"> Soporte T&eacute;cnico </a>
                        </li>

                    </ul>
                </li>

                <li>

                <li class="side-nav-title side-nav-item menu-title">Finanzas</li>

                <li>
                    <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="side-nav-link" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top"
                        title="Compra / Venta" aria-expanded="false">
                        <i class="bx bx-dollar"></i>
                        <span style="font-weight:700"> <?php echo $compraD ?> / <?php echo $ventaD?> </span>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="side-nav-link" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top"
                        title="Compra / Venta" aria-expanded="false">
                        <i class="bx bx-euro"></i>
                        <span style="font-weight:700"> <?php echo $compraE ?> / <?php echo $ventaE?></span>
                    </a>
                </li>

                <li class="side-nav-title side-nav-item menu-title socialesMTOP100">Redes Sociales</li>

                <li class="facebookBOTTOM10">
                    <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="side-nav-link" aria-expanded="false">
                        <i class='bx bxl-facebook'></i>
                        <span> Facebook </span>
                        <!-- <span class="menu-arrow"></span> -->
                    </a>

                </li>

                <li class="instagramBOTTOM5">
                    <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="side-nav-link" aria-expanded="false">
                        <i class='bx bxl-instagram'></i>
                        <span> Instagram </span>
                        <!-- <span class="menu-arrow"></span> -->
                    </a>
                </li>

                <li class="twitterBOTTOM0">
                    <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="side-nav-link" aria-expanded="false">
                    <i class='bx bxl-twitter' ></i>
                        <span> Twitter </span>
                        <!-- <span class="menu-arrow"></span> -->
                    </a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</aside>
```

Comment: No haz intentado ponerle un `position: relative;` al elemento padre de tus iconos?

Comment: Hola @JhonMaldonado, gracias por tu comentario, me explicas un poco mejor porque' deberia hacer eso? estoy explicando en mi pregunta que precisamente ese es mi problema. Saludos.

Comment: Cuando colocas `top: 950px;` lo que estás haciendo es mover un elemento a `950px` con respecto a tu sidebar, ya que este tiene establecido `position: relative;`, es decir, el `position: relative` sirve para establecer el punto de referencia que se usará para que puedas mover otros elementos con `position: absolute;`. Espero haberme explicado bien.